# Add multiple routes with info window in a single ol map

Tags: maps, openlayers, osrm

I am trying to get the multiple routes/directions with markers and line from start to end points. I have tried 2 different methods both using osrm api.

1. In the first one though I am getting the route, direction, and info window but it only shows for the first points, the rest don't appear.
2. In the 2nd one though I get multiple/all points but I get issues while getting directions for the points. The issues are

   -. It renders a blue image at the end which covers all of the map

   -. it shows direction lines but the markers get hidden.

First tried code

```js
var points = [],
        // msg_el = document.getElementById('msg'),
        url_osrm_nearest = '//router.project-osrm.org/nearest/v1/driving/',
        url_osrm_route = '//router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/',
        vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector(),
        vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vectorSource,
        }),
        
        styles = {
            route: new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                width: 3, color: [40, 4, 40, 0.8]
                })
            }),
            icon: new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Icon({
                anchor: [0.5, 1],
                // src: icon_url
                })
            })
        };

        // Pins
        const availablepin = "http://crm.gtmmtransportation.net/Assets/Images/available.png";

        console.clear();

        

        function createMarker(info, icon, content) {
            var marker, content, distance, duration;

            content = ' <div id="content" > ' +
                '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                '<h1 style="font-size: 15px;" id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading sa">' + content.unitNo + '</h1>' +
                "<div style='display: flex; flex-direction: column;align-items: self-end;margin-right: 10px;'>" +
                '<a href="' + content.holdlink + '" title="' + content.holdtt + '"class="hold ' + content.holdclass + '">' + content.holdcurrstat + '</a>' +
                "<p style='font-size: 12px;'>Last Updated By: " + content.status_updating_user + " </p>" +
                "</div>" +
                "</div>" +

                '<div class="bodyContent">' +
                "<span><b>Driver: </b></span><p class='sa'>" + content.driver + '<small style="color: var(--light-font);" > [' + content.loadcount  +  "/" + content.ratingaverage + "]</small></p> <br> " +
            "<span><b>Ph: </b></span><p  class='sa'>" + content.phonenumber + "</p> <br>" +
                "<span><b>Address: </b></span><a  class='sa' href='https://www.google.com/maps/place/" + encodeURIComponent(content.address) + "' target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer' style='color: #0e4ddb;'>" + content.address + "</a> <br>" +
                "<span><b>Arrival Date: </b></span><p  class='sa'>" + content.arrivalDate + "</p><br>" +
                "<span><b>Dims: </b></span><p  class='sa'>" + content.dimensions + "</p><br>" +
                "<span><b>Weight: </b></span><p  class='sa'>" + content.weight + "</p><br>" +
                "<span><b>Notes: </b></span><p  class='sa'>" + content.notes + "</p><br>" +
                "</div>" +
                "</div>";


            for(i=0; i< info.length; i++){
                // var last_point = ""
                i == 0 ? last_point = info[i] : last_point = info[i - 1]
                // var last_point = pointss[pointss.length - 1];
                // utils.createFeature(pointss[i]);
                var feature = new ol.Feature({
                    type: 'place',
                    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat(info[i])),
                    content: content
                });

                var src = i == 0 ? icon : 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/2.png';
               
                feature.setStyle(
                    new ol.style.Style({
                        image: new ol.style.Icon({
                            anchor: [0.5, 1],
                            src: src,
                            // size: [40, 40],
                            scale: 0.6
                            // width: '10'
                        })
                    }),
                )
                marker = vectorSource.addFeature(feature);

                //get the route
                var point1 = last_point.join();
                var point2 = info[i].join();
                
                fetch(url_osrm_route + point1 + ';' + point2).then(function(r) { 
                    return r.json();
                }).then(function(json) {
                    distance += (json.routes[0].distance)
                    duration += (json.routes[0].duration)
                    if(json.code !== 'Ok') {
                        return;
                    }
                    utils.createRoute(json.routes[0].geometry);
                });

                // this.map.removeLayers(this.markerGroup);
                // this.map.addLayers(this.markerGroup);

                // marker = L.marker(info, {
                //     icon: icon
                // }).addTo(markerLayer);
                // marker.bindPopup(content);

                // var id = marker._leaflet_id;
                // var id = null
                // if (document.getElementById(id) != null) return;
                // var sidebarElement, infoPart, removePart;
                // sidebarElement = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'sidebarElement', document.getElementById('sidebarElements'));
                // sidebarElement.id = id;

                // infoPart = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'infoSidebarElement', sidebarElement);
                // infoPart.innerHTML = content;
                // L.DomEvent.on(infoPart, 'mouseover', function(evt) {
                //     var marker = markerLayer.getLayer(this.id);
                //     marker.closePopup();
                //     marker.openPopup();
                // }, sidebarElement);
            }

            

        }

        // Available
        var availableunit = [{
                elat: 43.6671042,elng: -116.691093,lat: 42.3986045,lng: -114.5613507,content: 
                {lat: 42.3986045,lng: -114.5613507,holdlink: './Assets/backendfiles/driverstatus.php?action_type=hold&id=36&redirect=maps.php&last_Status=available&username=Ian',holdtt: 'Click to Put on Hold',holdclass: 'hold-danger',holdcurrstat: 'Hold',unitNo: '1051',driver: 'Pedro Bustos',phonenumber: '(208) 358-4460',arrivalDate: '2023-03-20',dimensions: '26ft Box Truck',weight: '',address: 'Twin Falls, ID 83301, USA',notes: '',status_updating_user: '',loadcount: '0',ratingaverage: '0',}},
                {
                elat: 43.6671042,elng: -116.691093,lat: 43.6189362,lng: -116.5346883,
                content: {lat: 43.6189362,lng: -116.5346883,holdlink: './Assets/backendfiles/driverstatus.php?action_type=hold&id=698&redirect=maps.php&last_Status=available&username=Ian',holdtt: 'Click to Put on Hold',holdclass: 'hold-danger',holdcurrstat: 'Hold',unitNo: '1625',driver: ' Frederic Karangwa',phonenumber: '208-230-3901',arrivalDate: '2023-03-16',dimensions: '128x51x70',weight: '3000',address: 'Nampa, ID 83687, USA',notes: '',status_updating_user: '',loadcount: '0',ratingaverage: '0',}}
                ]


        

        function mapimp(arr, icon) {

            if(arr !== ''){
                for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    
                    createMarker([[arr[i].lng, arr[i].lat], [arr[i].elng, arr[i].elat]], icon, arr[i].content);
                }
            }
            
        }

        var center = ol.proj.fromLonLat([-93.59277789139063, 41.590686510484915]);
        markerGroup = new ol.layer.Group({
            layers: [],
            name: 'markerGroup'
        });
        var map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [ this.markerGroup ],
            // [
            //     new ol.layer.Tile({
            //         source: new ol.source.OSM(),
            //     }),
            //     vectorLayer
            // ],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: center,
                zoom: 5,
                maxZoom: 18,
            }),
        });
        map.setTarget($("#map")[0]);

        mapimp(availableunit, availablepin)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.10.1/ol.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.10.1/ol.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>GTMM TRANSPORTATION | MAP</title>

    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Assets/css/style.css">

    <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            margin-left: 10%;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        

        .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper,
        .leaflet-popup-tip {
            padding: 10px;
        }

        #sidebar {
            position: absolute;
            width: 20%;
            height: 100%;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
            overflow: auto;
        }

        .sidebarElement {
            padding: 10px 15px;
            display: table;
            width: 88%;
            border-top: 1px solid #dadada;
            margin: 0 10px;
        }

        .sidebarElement:hover {
            background-color: #eeeeee;
        }

        .sidebarElement .bodyContent span,
        .sidebarElement .bodyContent br {
            display: none;
        }

        .sidebarElement .bodyContent p,
        .sidebarElement .bodyContent a {
            font-size: 12px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            line-height: 0;
            line-break: loose;
        }

        .sidebarElement #siteNotice {
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            margin-right: 0px;
        }

        .sidebarElement #siteNotice .hold {
            height: 33px;
        }

        .sidebarElement .bodyContent p::after,
        .sidebarElement .bodyContent a::after {
            content: " : ";
            color: red;
        }

        font {
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 600;
            color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
        }

        .infoSidebarElement {
            display: table-cell;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 90%;
        }

        .removeSidebarElement {
            display: table-cell;
            text-align: right;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #counts {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 10px;
            background-color: #ffff;
            z-index: 1000;
            border-radius: 7px;
        }

        #search {
            margin: 10px;
            border-top-right-radius: 0;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
            width: 75%;
        }

        .searchicon {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #dadada;
            padding: 3.5px 5px;
            margin-left: -10px;
            border-top-right-radius: 7px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
        }

        .searchdiv {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            width: 2fr;
            flex: 3;
            width: 80%;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        #content p {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: contents;
            color: #8b8b8b;
        }

        #content span {
            color: #8b8b8b;
        }

        .bodyContent {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .searchcontainer {
            position: fixed;
            overflow: hidden;
            background: #fafafa;
            top: 0;
            width: 18%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        #siteNotice {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            margin-top: -7px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            margin-right: -10px;
        }

        .hold {
            height: 26px;
        }

        .closest_u_container {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 400;
            top: 33px;
            /* right: calc(63% - 350px); */
            background: #fff;
            border-radius: 8px;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        #loading-bar-spinner.spinner {
            left: 50%;
            /* margin-left: -20px; */
            top: 50%;
            /* margin-top: -20px; */
            /* position: absolute; */
            z-index: 19 !important;
            animation: loading-bar-spinner 900ms linear infinite;
        }

        #loading-bar-spinner.spinner .spinner-icon {
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            border: solid 4px transparent;
            border-top-color: #00C8B1 !important;
            border-left-color: #00C8B1 !important;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

        @keyframes loading-bar-spinner {
            0%   { transform: rotate(0deg);   transform: rotate(0deg); }
            100% { transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <style>
        canvas{
            width: 100% !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            margin-left: auto;
        }

        #map {
        position: relative;
        }
        #info {
            position: absolute;
            /* height: 1px; */
            /* width: 1px; */
            z-index: 10000;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            max-width: 315px;
        }
        .tooltip.in {
        opacity: 1;
        }
        .tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow {
        border-top-color: white;
        }
        .tooltip-inner {
        border: 2px solid white;
        }
    </style>


    <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="searchcontainer">
            <div class="searchdiv">
                <input type="search" name="search" id="search" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search...">
                <div class="searchicon"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></div>
            </div>
            <select name="filter" style="flex: 1;width: 25%;">
                <option>Unit No</option>
                <option>Driver Name</option>
                <option>Phone Number</option>
                <option>Location</option>
                <option>Date</option>
                <option>Dimensions</option>
                <option>Weight</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div id="sidebarElements" style="margin-top: 50px;"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="map">
        <div id="info"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="closest_u_container">
        <input type="text" id="start" placeholder="Search to get the closest units"  style="width: 350px">
        <input type="hidden" name="closest_lat" id="closest_lat" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="closest_lng" id="closest_lng" value="">
        <button type="reset" id="reset" style="position: relative;">RESET</button>
    </div>
    <div id="counts" style="padding: 10px;"><span>Total Units: </span><span id="count" style="font-weight: 500; color: red;"></span></div>

    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.10.1/ol.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.10.1/ol.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
 </body>
</html>
```

2nd Tried Code

```js
// Create a map instance
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]),
    zoom: 2
  })
});

// Define the OSRM API URL and route coordinates
var osrmUrl = 'https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/';
var routes = [
  { origin: [-116.5346883, 43.6189362], destination: [-116.691093, 43.6671042] },
  { origin: [-114.5613507, 42.3986045], destination: [-116.691093, 43.6671042] }
];



// Create an array to store the route features
var routeFeatures = [];

// Create a separate layer for marker features
var markerLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector(),
  style: function (feature) {
    return new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 6,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'blue'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'white',
          width: 2
        })
      }),
      zIndex: Infinity // Ensure markers are displayed above other layers
    });
  }
});

// Fetch routes and create features for each route
routes.forEach(function (route) {
  fetch(osrmUrl + route.origin[0] + ',' + route.origin[1] + ';' + route.destination[0] + ',' + route.destination[1] + '?overview=full&geometries=geojson')
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      var routeCoordinates = data.routes[0].geometry.coordinates;
     
      var routeFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(routeCoordinates)
        // type: 'route',
        // geometry: droute
      });

      routeFeatures.push(routeFeature);

      // Create marker features for the starting and ending points
      var startMarker = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat(route.origin))
      });
      var endMarker = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat(route.destination))
      });
    //   console.log(markerLayer)

      markerLayer.getSource().addFeature(startMarker);
      markerLayer.getSource().addFeature(endMarker);

      // Check if all routes have been fetched
      if (routeFeatures.length === routes.length) {
        // Create a route layer
        // console.log("routes adding")
        // console.log(routeFeatures)
        var routeLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
          source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: routeFeatures
          }),
          style: new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: 'red',
              width: 2
            })
          })
        //   console.log()
        });
        // console.log(routeLayer)

        // Add the route layer and marker layer to the map
        map.addLayer(routeLayer);
        map.addLayer(markerLayer);

        // Fit the map view to the extent of all routes
        // var routesExtent = ol.extent.createEmpty();
        // var routesExtent = ol.extent;
        // console.log(routesExtent)
        // routeFeatures.forEach(function (feature) {
        //     console.log(feature.getGeometry().getExtent())
        //   ol.extent.extend(routesExtent, feature.getGeometry().getExtent());
        // });
        // map.getView().fit(routesExtent, { padding: [50, 50, 50, 50] });

        // Fit the map view to the extent of all routes
        // console.log(ol.extent.boundingExtent())
        var routesExtent = ol.extent.boundingExtent(
          routeFeatures.map(function (feature) {
            // console.log("route extent feture")

            // console.log(feature)
            return feature.getGeometry().getExtent();
          })
        );
        // console.log("route")
        // console.log(routeFeatures)
        // console.log("marker")
        // console.log(markerLayer)
        // var markerExtent = ol.extent.boundingExtent(
        //   function (markerLayer) {
        //     // console.log("route extent feture")

        //     // console.log(feature)
        //     return markerLayer.getGeometry().getExtent();
        //   }
        // );
        console.log(routesExtent)
        map.getView().fit( { padding: [50, 50, 50, 50] });

        // Fit the map view to the extent of all routes
        // var routesExtent = ol.extent.create();
        // routeFeatures.forEach(function (feature) {
        //   ol.extent.extend(routesExtent, feature.getGeometry().getExtent());
        // });
        // map.getView().fit(routesExtent, { padding: [50, 50, 50, 50] });
    }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('Error:', error);
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.6.1/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.6.1/build/ol.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.6.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <style>
    .map {
      height: 400px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>

  <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.6.1/build/ol.js"></script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second attempt you need to transform the route coordinates to view projection (similar to calling `fromLonlat` on the start and end points) otherwise your route is very small and close to the equator in the Atlantic near Africa.

```
    geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(routeCoordinates).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
```

`ol.extent.boundingExtent` gets the bounding extent of coordinates, to combine extents use `ol.extent.extend`

```
    var routesExtent = ol.extent.createEmpty();
    routeFeatures.forEach(function (feature) {
       ol.extent.extend(routesExtent, feature.getGeometry().getExtent());
    });
```

```js
// Create a map instance
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]),
    zoom: 2
  })
});

// Define the OSRM API URL and route coordinates
var osrmUrl = 'https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/';
var routes = [
  { origin: [-116.5346883, 43.6189362], destination: [-116.691093, 43.6671042] },
  { origin: [-114.5613507, 42.3986045], destination: [-116.691093, 43.6671042] }
];



// Create an array to store the route features
var routeFeatures = [];

// Create a separate layer for marker features
var markerLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector(),
  style: function (feature) {
    return new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 6,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'blue'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'white',
          width: 2
        })
      }),
      zIndex: Infinity // Ensure markers are displayed above other layers
    });
  }
});

// Fetch routes and create features for each route
routes.forEach(function (route) {
  fetch(osrmUrl + route.origin[0] + ',' + route.origin[1] + ';' + route.destination[0] + ',' + route.destination[1] + '?overview=full&geometries=geojson')
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      var routeCoordinates = data.routes[0].geometry.coordinates;
     
      var routeFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(routeCoordinates).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
        // type: 'route',
        // geometry: droute
      });

      routeFeatures.push(routeFeature);

      // Create marker features for the starting and ending points
      var startMarker = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat(route.origin))
      });
      var endMarker = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat(route.destination))
      });
    //   console.log(markerLayer)

      markerLayer.getSource().addFeature(startMarker);
      markerLayer.getSource().addFeature(endMarker);

      // Check if all routes have been fetched
      if (routeFeatures.length === routes.length) {
        // Create a route layer
        // console.log("routes adding")
        // console.log(routeFeatures)
        var routeLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
          source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: routeFeatures
          }),
          style: new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: 'red',
              width: 2
            })
          })
        //   console.log()
        });
        // console.log(routeLayer)

        // Add the route layer and marker layer to the map
        map.addLayer(routeLayer);
        map.addLayer(markerLayer);

        var routesExtent = ol.extent.createEmpty();
        routeFeatures.forEach(function (feature) {
           ol.extent.extend(routesExtent, feature.getGeometry().getExtent());
        });
   
        map.getView().fit(routesExtent, { padding: [50, 50, 50, 50] });

    }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('Error:', error);
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.6.1/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.6.1/build/ol.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.6.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <style>
    .map {
      height: 400px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>

  <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.6.1/build/ol.js"></script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```